# Being blocked by email servers constantly

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I have a shared hosting service and this is the first time I am using it for email. It has been 2 weeks and everyday I am getting different mail rejection errors. My provider changed the IP of the server but nothing actually changed (it worked for a day than got blocked) again.

Some popular error I get are;

SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:: host virusgw.sadecehosting.com [77.92.152.16]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [37.230.110.43] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; http://www.spamhaus.org

SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:: host mail.yucelboru.com.tr [95.0.202.85]: 550 5.7.1 :127.0.0.4:Client host 37.230.110.43 blocked using 87.blocklist.zap; Mail from IP banned. To request remova

SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection: host smtp2.garanti.com.tr [194.29.208.127]: 554-smtp2.garanti.com.tr\n554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believ

My provider says they fixed it and again it happens...I do not get why? Everyting used to be smooth but now can not figure it out. We have a cPanel connection but I can not manage most of the things...It is a reseller cpanel account.

Any advice would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're blacklisted.

Looks to me like you've been listed as a source of spam by a few different places. This does not bode well, and it's a pain to get off these lists.

You may want to take a look at [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user). cPanel is notoriously insecure, and it wouldn't surprise me if you discovered **your server** really is the source of spam. Make sure you have your mail server set up properly. It's quite an undertaking though, and you may be better off shelling out $5 per mailbox instead of going insane.

Answer (score 0):

Send yourself a Mail and check headers. You should make sure that they make sense, i.e. they do not display other servers / IPs thet they really came from (i.e. you did not by mistake write the recipient into the from-header. Servers would reject this as obvious fake). Compare with a mail sent from a known mail host to see differences.